# odoo PyCharm configuration / no module named 'odoo'

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo

I'm newbee in programming and I need some help.

I have to work with PyCharm and Odoo, so my point is to configure PyCharm for Odoo debugging. First of all I made a module and a model, it perfectly work with database(i can see and check it).
I want PyCharm not to highlight word 'odoo', 'models' and 'fields' by red line(unresolved reference) or green line(Package containing module 'odoo' is not listed in project requirements)

I've read lots of tutorials and manuals but nothing helps me.
I think the problem is that PyCharm doesn't see the odoo package (or smth like that).
There is no odoo in requirements.txt

So, I need to coonect PyCharm and Odoo, without red or green underlining. PyCharm doesn't see the Odoo module.
Maybe the problem with the fact that my project folder located not in odoo main folder, but maybe im wrong.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: try changing on addons folder web_kanban_gauge to web_kanban

Comment: You might be running python2. From odoo 11, you are supposed to use python3.

Comment: No, I'm using python 3.7, odoo 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
You just need to add odoo folder to the source folder of the project in PyCharm settings:
File - Settings - Project Structure - + Add content root
There you should pick Odoo13\server folder

Answer (score 0):

**Install** and **create** virtualenv and install odoo. Then **add** virtualenv path to pycharm.

Comment: Intersting advice, thanks! I'll try. But I don't understand how to install odoo in virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks, now there is no highlighting under words odoo and models, fields